# population distribution & sampling distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

What is the difference between the population distribution of a random variable X and the sampling distribution of a random variable that is a sample statistic?

This is a question I got from my econometrics teacher, but I'm very uncertain about the terms that she uses.
It would help me greatly if some simple and straightforward explanation can be given.
Thank you in advance.